# tmux - List output last line of all windows in new window

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tmux, terminal-multiplexer

I am running a tmux session with 40 windows. I need to create an overview window listing the last line of each screen and updating each listing as the output of the respective window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to enumerate all the windows, or rather all the panes, since a window can have several of them. Then capture the output of each pane and display the last line of captured text. Put this into a script:

```
tmux list-windows -F '#I'  |   
  while read w; do tmux list-panes -F '#P' -t $w | 
     while read p; do echo -n  "${w}.${p}" ; tmux capture-pane -p -t "${w}.${p}" | 
        tail -n 1 
     done 
  done
```

Suppose you put this code in `/some/file`
After that, being in your 40 window tmux session, you create your new monitoring window, and run

```
watch -n 1 'bash /some/file'
```

in there. The `echo -n  "${w}.${p}" ;` part will prepend the lines with the window and pane index, I found it's rather useful to have an idea of the output origin. You may not want it.

Comment: This works! thanks! However, the colors and indentation of the original output are lost. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Not really. Though you can preserve any escape sequences with -e option of capture-pane command you still will need to have somtehting to handle them correctly. tail cannot that but I think that may give you the direction.